# Storing hardcoded Strings securely in Binary

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm looking for a way to store hardcoded strings securely in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android apps. This would be used to store sensitive configuration data directly embbeded in the app binary.

What are the best methods of doing this?

Comment: Do you want encrypted strings? You can write code,  generating the string. You know that the user can do everything with the code, if it are some configurations about networking, you should probably configure your server.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way to store hardcoded strings securely in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android apps.

The easiest way is to create a shared PCL for your `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.iOS` apps or directly leveraging `Xamarin.Forms` as your project template and leverage [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto/) for data encryption.

And here is the [sample for usage of PCLCrypto](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto/tree/master/samples/PCLCryptoSample).